# SQL Server : update rows takes a long time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

We use SQL Server 2017. We need to a 1 time only update on a table that has about 1.5 million rows.

Before the update, we changed the database recovery model temporarily from "Full" to "Simple", and run this query to commit transaction every 50,000 rows:

```
declare @LastCount int
set ROWCOUNT 50000
set @LastCount = 1

while (@LastCount > 0)
begin
    begin tran
        update myTbl 
        set SendPath = replace(SendPath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') ,
            ReceivePath = replace(ReceivePath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') 

        set @LastCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    commit tran
end
set ROWCOUNT 0
```

The above statement takes a long time to execute (when I stopped it after 2 hours, it's still not finished yet).

Since the database is now a Simple Recovery Model, do I still need to do the commit tran for every x number of records ?

Or, can I simply just execute this query without the begin tran and commit tran ?

```
update myTbl 
set SendPath = replace(SendPath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') ,
    ReceivePath = replace(ReceivePath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder')
```

Based on the recommendations, I updated the query to this, and now it runs fast:

```
declare @LastCount int
set ROWCOUNT 50000
set @LastCount = 1

while (@LastCount > 0)
begin
    begin tran

        update myTbl 
        set SendPath = replace(SendPath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') ,
            ReceivePath = replace(ReceivePath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') 
        where left(SendPath,31) = '\\Server1\myFolder\'

        set @LastCount = @@ROWCOUNT
    commit tran
end
set ROWCOUNT 0
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you have a loop there? That is one update statement changing the whole table.

Comment: The loop is to commit transaction every 50,000 records (per our DBA recommendation). Should I just do "update myTbl set 
SendPath = replace(SendPath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') ,
ReceivePath = replace(ReceivePath,'\\Server1\myFolder\','\\Server2\myFolder') " ?

Comment: Your DBA didn't give you all of the recommendation, they also need to tell you that your query needs to _target_ only that many rows at a time. I talk about the pattern I use here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6966/sql-while-loop-avoid-while-1-equals-1/ ... which is also the key to your problem because basically `@@ROWCOUNT` will _always_ be 50,000 and _never_ 0. You're just updating the same 50,000 rows over and over again. Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: @faujong you've done nothing in your query to restrict it to 50,000 rows at a time, since you have no `WHERE` clause it updates every record on the first run through, then runs the query over and over, since it still technically updated every single row with the same value. You have an infinite loop here.

Comment: @Andrew it's worse than that. If he didn't press stop it would _still_ be updating the same 50,000 rows over and over and over and over...

Comment: @AaronBertrand yeah realized that - since even though the replace does nothing on the second+ iteration, it still updates the values to their current results. It's not even updating just 50k rows, it's doing them all every time

Comment: @Larnu That would fix the infinite looping issue, but wouldn't resolve the DBA requesting it be handled in multiple batched transactions.

Comment: Hi all, Yes, You are correct. My bad. I added the WHERE clause (I edited the original query) , and now the query runs very fast

Comment: Thank you all for your quick replies.

Comment: Also - not sure what you're trying to achieve with this 50'000 rows batch size. SQL Server will internally go from a row-level exclusive lock to a **table-wide exclusive lock** when a transaction affects more than **5'000** rows - so even with your batching, you'll still be **exclusively locking** the entire table each time, so that not even `SELECT` will work against the table, until your `UPDATE` is done...... so **IF** you introduce batching - you should really stay **below 5000 rows** to avoid table-level exclusive locks

Comment: Does it matter if no other process is accessing the database when I execute this UPDATE statement ?

Comment: Nice point @marc_s!

Comment: @marc_s It's still beneficial, because it stops the transaction log going berserk, at least under full recovery.

Comment: If no-one is accessing the database, and you are in simple recovery, the fastest way to do this is to do the whole thing in one shot

Comment: @Charlieface That depends - is the goal really speed in this case? It might be to prevent the transaction log from growing out of control, which can still happen even in simple recovery with a single transaction that updates 1.5 million rows.

Comment: @AaronBertrand As a one off operation (which it is in this case), I would probably expand the log before and shrink it afterwards. That's not out of control, that's a controlled explosion :-) After all, OP is complaining "takes a long time"

Comment: Right but (1) that's different from :"just do it all in one shot" and (2) the reason might be that there isn't enough room to expand the log.